# What word describes the opposite of 'elevated'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume things are graded in some way and some level is assigned the attribute 'normal'. 
Things which stay (always) above this level are called elevated (relative to the norm). Things which stay (always) below this level are called what?

Edit: I have intentionally omitted a closer context because I am interested in the most general applicable word. But: the word should be used in a technical, neutral sense, not in a moral judgment.

Edit 2: The answer I choose is in fact a comment by @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: "There is no canonical generally applicable word."

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/elevated

Comment: There are numerous possibilities as reflected in the link @mplungjan offers. Many of these have different tones or common usages depending on the context. Medicine, money, weather, personal characteristics each may call for a different response. More info please.

Comment: After looking at the link mplungjan provided I feel that FrustratedWithFormsDesigner might me right: that there is no canonical generally applicable word.

Comment: Not really sure what value you're looking for people to add — I can see what you'd specifically ask if you *did* want a certain conntext, but if you're not going to give any background, isn't a thesaurus the best bet?

Comment: @anotherdave I have commented on this before. In the thesaurus an example sentence is: "Psychological studies also indicate that highly creative people share an elevated risk of serious mental illness." This comes near to my intended use.

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment so, just saw that you said in a technical sense, but that would depend on which field you're being technical in :) From your comment, I'd most likely go with *FrustratedWithFormsDesigner*: 'reduced' would fit well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lowered" or "reduced" might work, but it's hard to say without some context.

Example:

> Bob has an elevated level of foo.
>
> Joe has a reduced level of foo.

Other phrases that might work are "less-than-average", "below-average", "subpar".

Comment: Or, depending on context, _submerged_ or _underground_.

Comment: I have intentionally omitted a closer context because I am interested in the most general applicable word.

Comment: @SophiaAntipolis: I'm not sure there is a canonical generally applicable word. My personal choice would probably depend on context.

Comment: My vague feeling is to search something which derives from the Latin 'supprimere'. But 'supprimated' seems not to exist.

Answer (score 3):

"depressed" or "diminished" might be appropriate for your context (which I am not entire clear on).

Comment: I agree with *depressed*.

Answer (score 0):

Deflated would be one possible choice among many.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going with deelavated, it's the only answer that really makes sense to me...

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining why you'd use a neologism (as it seems to be).